# how to hover over text while changing colors at the same time using css?

Tags: css

I am trying to change the color of each letter in a word when one moves mouse across word, like from red to pink to green. I have been attempting this with CSS but no luck. How could I make this happen?

Comment: Add your code. It's difficult to say anything without it.

Comment: You want to wrap each letter in a `<span>`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap each letter in an element like span. Then you can add a `hover` selector to the css. Something like this:

```css
span:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span>H</span>
<span>e</span>
<span>l</span>
<span>l</span>
<span>o</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use on javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var letters = $('p').text();
  var nHTML = '';
  for(var letter of letters) {
    nHTML+="<span class='x'>"+letter+"</span>";
  }
  $('p').html(nHTML);
})
```

```css
.x:hover {
  color: orange;
  font-size:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

Comment: so you get your answer in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50422767/how-change-color-of-letter-on-mouse-hover-in-javascript then you simply do a copy/paste :) it' not a good behavior

Comment: @TemaniAfif , The main idea was mine, And I had a problem in part of the code so,get help from others.I'm asking for this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50422767/how-change-color-of-letter-on-mouse-hover-in-javascript. i posted my question after this question.see Look at the date .

Comment: `The main idea was mine` --> this question was asked before. And I know that the other question was yours and since you already get an answer you don't simply copy/past it to *help* other. You flag as duplicate or you add comments. This a simple copy/paste and such behavior is prohibited.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, ok,bay

Comment: I apologize for the common question, new to stackoverflow. I have since edited my question. Thank you for the help.