# How to change color of letter on mouse hover in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var letters = $('p').text();
  for(var letter of letters) {
    $(letter).wrap("<span class='x'></span>");
  }
})
```

```css
.x:hover {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

For example, I want when hovering on `r`, the color of `r` to be `orange` and no other letters.

Comment: I suggest to take a look to lettering.js

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can first create a new HTML content using `<span class='x'>` for each character in `<p>` and then replace the HTML of `<p>` with that HTML. Now, when you hover over each character then the color of that character changes to `orange`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var letters = $('p').text();
  var nHTML = '';
  for(var letter of letters) {
    nHTML+="<span class='x'>"+letter+"</span>";
  }
  $('p').html(nHTML);
})
```

```css
.x:hover {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

Comment: @Ehsan you can use that but you should also make sure your DOM is updated

Comment: @Ehsan better to keep things simple by concatenation like a string. Easy and fast

Comment: @Ehsan You can, but you can't use `$(letter)`. You need to do something like `$(document.createTextNode(letter))` that you can `wrap` and then append to the DOM.

Comment: @Ehsan I said "append to the DOM", not "concatenate with a string"

Answer (score 10):

You can wrap every letter with a span with class `x` for example.

**Example:**

```js
$("#x").html(
  $("#x").text().split("").map(a => `<span class="x">${a}</span>`)
)
```

```css
.x:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="x">Hello World!</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely solve this problem using CSS. Create a div and inside write a text command with an id. Use the id to reference it in CSS.

```
.id:hover{
    color: blue;
}
```